# How to use Awk to create a new field but retain the original field?

Tags: awk, sed

Can this be done in Awk?

FILE_IN (Input file)

```
ID_Number|Title|Name
65765765|The Cat Sat on the Mat|Dennis Smith
65765799|The Dog Sat on the Catshelf|David Jones
65765797|The Horse Sat on the Sofa|Jeff Jones
```

FILE_OUT (Desired Results)

```
ID_Number|Title|Nickname|Name
65765765|The Cat Sat on the Mat|Cat Sat|Dennis Smith
65765799|The Dog Sat on the Catshelf|Dog|David Jones
65765797|The Horse Sat on the Sofa||Jeff Jones
```

Logic to apply:

```
IF Title contains “ Cat Sat ” OR " cat sat " THEN Nickname = “Cat Sat” #same titlecase/text as was found#
IF Title contains “ Dog ” OR " dog " THEN Nickname = “Dog”
```

Also, is this task possible with Sed?

Comment: Does upper/lower case matter? If `cat` appears in Title then should the nickname in the output be `cat` or `Cat` or nothing? What about partial matches, e.g. if Title is `My Catamaran sank` then it contains `Cat` so should the nickname Cat be added? Does position matter? In your example it's always the 2nd word of Title where the keyword appears, is that always true? How about `My friend is a real hound dog`? Think about edge cases and include THOSE in your sample input/output, not just the sunny day cases.

Comment: With sed: possible, but strongly discouraged.

Comment: Ed:  I've edited the question.

Comment: What's the expected output for `65765765|The Cat Sat on the Dog Bed|Dennis Smith`? I feel like there's more requirements to this question than you've told us so far so I for one am reluctant to jump in and start guessing...

Comment: Ed:  If "first match" is found use that to set Nickname e.g. Cat Sat.  Then ignore any further matches e.g. Dog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another `awk`

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} 
            {delete a; 
             match($2,"([Cc]at [Ss]at|[Dd]og)",a); 
             $NF=(NR==1?"Nickname":a[1]) OFS $NF}1' file

ID_Number|Title|Nickname|Name
65765765|The Cat Sat on the Mat|Cat Sat|Dennis Smith
65765799|The Dog Sat on the Catshelf|Dog|David Jones
65765797|The Horse Sat on the Sofa||Jeff Jones
```

Comment: I think the array argument is `gawk` specific.  If you're using a different implementation you should use `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` to get the matched string out of the field.

Comment: I'm using GNU Awk 4.2.1 (2018) on Mac OS X.  Should the Match command work there?

Comment: I think it should, not sure what the problem might be.  Perhaps post the error message?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '1s/|/&Nickname&/2;1b;s/|.*\b\(Cat\|Dog\)\b.*|/&\u\1|/I;t;s/|.*|/&|/' file
```

Insert the column `Nickname` into the headings. If the second column contains either the word `Cat` or `Dog` insert a third column with the matching word in it. Otherwise insert a blank third column.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this with GNU `awk`:

```
awk -F"|" -v OFS="|" 'NR==1{$2 = $2 OFS "Nickname"} 
NR>1{if($0 ~ /\s*[Cc]at [Ss]at\s+/) n="Cat"; else if($0 ~ /\s*[dD]og\s+/)n="Dog";
else n=""; $2 = $2 OFS n}  1' file
```

- `-F "|" OFS="|"` to specify delimiter input and output respectively.
- `NR==1` To handle header case.
- `NR>1` To handle data case.

With the same logic, you could use this more compacted code:

```
awk -F"|" -v OFS="|" 'NR==1{$2 = $2 OFS "Nickname"} 
NR>1{n=($0 ~ /\s*[Cc]at [Ss]at\s+/) ? "Cat" : ($0 ~ /\s*[dD]og\s+/) ? "Dog" : ""; $2 = $2 OFS n}  1' file
```

Comment: Seems to work for "Dog" but not sure of correct syntax to use for "Cat Sat".