# Add a serial number as sequence to each line in a file in UNIX at specific position

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a Unix file with multiple lines and fields comma separated.
I need to insert a new field in each line as a serial number (1,2,3 ..) on the 3rd position after the comma

> Text Before

```
roy,mike,apple,alex
roy,apple,water,joe
lemon,tony,juice,fred
```

> Text After

```
roy,mike,apple,1,alex
roy,apple,water,2,joe
lemon,tony,juice,3,fred
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Awk to create a new field but retain the original field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51730561/how-to-use-awk-to-create-a-new-field-but-retain-the-original-field)

Comment: Single line awk: `awk -vOFS=, -F,  '{ print $1, $2, $3, ++n, $4 }'`

Comment: @dash-o there's no difference between `NR` and `++n`.

Comment: It's cryptic in sed: `sed '=' filename | sed 'N;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*,\)/\2\1,/'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a more correct answer, since it asked for inserting a field after 3 column, not the second last as in Ravinders answer

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{$3=$3FS FNR}1' file
roy,mike,apple,1,alex
roy,apple,water,2,joe
lemon,tony,juice,3,fred
```

Answer (score 5):

Though link shared by [oguz ismail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10248678/oguz-ismail) but seems link's solutions are a bit complex compare to this problem, so adding a simple one here.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$NF=++count OFS $NF} 1'  Input_file
```

OR as per anubhava sir's comment you could try following too.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$NF = FNR OFS $NF} 1' Input_file
```

These solutions assume that the sequence number must be inserted before the last field (`$NF`) as shown in question.

`FNR` is the record number in the individual input file. If you specify more than one file on the command line, this number will jump back to 1 for every new file. If you want the sequence number to continue counting over all input files use `NR` instead of `FNR`.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, -vOFS=, '{$4=NR}1' filename
```